# How to achieve glow effect in 3d game using Opengl ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx, effects, glow

I am making 3d game and I am wondering how to do glow effect on particular parts of my world(i.e explosions, sun). I am using libgdx and there is particle effect creator, but only for 2d world.  [image: sun]

Comment: use this :-http://code.google.com/p/min3d/ and make your life easy :)

Comment: Thanks for link, but I can't see how can this help me. I am already using libgdx for rendering things(not only ofc).

Comment: Glow is usually implemented by blurring a down-sampled copy of an image that contains only the really bright parts of the scene. It is not (typically) done using particles. Depending on the desired quality and available fill-rate (probably next to none in OpenGL ES), you might approach it slightly differently. On the really cheap end of things, you could just scale a point sprite slightly larger than the object that's supposed to be glowing and use an additive blend mode.